# Excel Index Match or Vlookup and copy

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vlookup

I have a sheet 1 with 3 columns as shown below. I have another sheet named sheet 2 with only the first names in Column A that are the same and found on sheet 1 column A.

[image]

[image]

I would like to write a formula in column B of Sheet 2 which matches the first name in Sheet 1 Column A against the first name in Column A and matches "no" found in column C and copies the information found in column B in Sheet 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use INDEX/MATCH in exact matching mode with wildcards.

B1 to B4 in the second sheet would be:

```
=IF(UPPER(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:Sheet1!$C$4,MATCH(A4&"*",Sheet1!$A$1:Sheet1!$A$4,0),3))="NO",INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:Sheet1!$C$4,MATCH(A4&"*",Sheet1!$A$1:Sheet1!$A$4,0),2),"")
```

Excel takes care of case mismatch and in sheet1 the names have the first alphabet capitalized.

The example below is slightly different from the example in the author's post to demonstrate that the list of names in Column A in the second sheet can be in any order. So Bob is repeated on A3 and as expected doesn't have any output in B3 since Bob had 'Yes' in the C column in the first sheet.

[image]

Comment: Your answer is a little confusing.  The formula looks like what would go in B4 but the description refers to B1.  And if you started with a formula in B1 and copied it down, B3 should also have an entry.

Comment: The author's question seemed to suggest that only the entries in Column B which had 'No' in the corresponding cell in column C should be displayed.
You are right, I copied it down, and the blank cells are because the first names in column A didn't have 'no' in the corresponding cell in column C on sheet 1. Notice that the first name for B3 is Bob, which is used as an example to show that the first names don't have to be in the sequence that they are listed in column A in sheet 1

Comment: Suggestions: On the 2nd line of the answer, change B1 to B4 to reflect which cell the formula is for, or change the formula to reflect what's in cell B1 to match the description.  Also, add a sentence to explain that your data is different from the example, and you've changed A3 to demonstrate a feature.  It's always clearer to avoid internal inconsistencies, and to highlight things that are different from the example in the question; it saves readers' brain cells.  :-)  Otherwise, good solution. +1

Answer (score 0):

One option is to just add a column that strips out just the first names from column A of your Sheet 1.  Then you can use this column as a reference.

Step 1: insert a new column in Sheet 1 between the current A and B columns, and paste this formula in the first row (assuming your first row contains the actual data- if not change the "1" in "A1" to be whatever the first row is): `=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)`.  Drag this formula down the length of the worksheet.  This will create a column of the first names.

Step 2: Now, you can reference the column of first names in your VLOOKUP on Sheet 2.  For example, in Sheet 2 column B paste this formula: `=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!B1:D4,3,FALSE)` and drag it down.  Of course you may need to change the exact rows that the formulas are referencing as your example does not indicate the row numbers.

Voila!

*Edit based on need to only return the records that have "no" in column C*

...finally, just wrap the Vlookup in an IF statement and drag the formula down as you did before:

`IF (Sheet1!C1="no", VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!B1:D4,3,FALSE),"")`

Comment: Close but not quite.  The goal is what is in original column B if original column C is "no".

Comment: hmm, that's not the way I interpreted the prompt. @Saul Gatica perhaps you can clear up your question.  I interpreted your need as you just want to return the value in Sheet 1 Column C regardless of whether the value is "yes" or "no"

Comment: @RyanChase the second part to the formula is to have another match for all names that have "no" on column C

Comment: @saul-gatica I've updated my answer per the need to only return the first names from records where "no" is listed in column C. Please accept the answer by clicking on the check mark on the left-hand side if it meets your need. Thanks.